# Cobra/Viper-like crate for CLI/config in Rust

Tags: rust

Can anyone suggest a stable and easy to use crate that will support in writing CLI and configs in Rust? In Go there's two complimentary solutions that work in unison to handle flag parsing and config management. Would be great if something similar existed for Rust.

PS. cursory search indicates that Clap looks somewhat similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes checkout [clap](https://clap.rs/), and [structopt](https://crates.io/crates/structopt) builds on top of clap and provides a nice experience.  Check out the official Rust cli getting started guide [here](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, Clap feels very familiar. Not sure why this question was off topic....but ok. Sure.